# Host system keyboard layout changes when starting LXC container

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, archlinux, lxc

I successfully created an archlinux container on an archlinux host with lxc. However, whenever I start a container via

```
    lxc-start -n GUESTNAME
```

the keyboard layout changes to the default us-layout on the host and in the container. But I want it to be de-latin1. What is surprising is that this keeps happening despite the fact that in

```
    /etc/vconsole.conf
```

on the host and in the container I have set the options

```
    KEYMAP=de-latin1
```

The cause of this problem seems to be that the systemd service responsible for setting the vconsole options is not running inside the container:

```
            systemctl status systemd-vconsole-setup
     ● systemd-vconsole-setup.service - Setup Virtual Console
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service; static)
       Active: inactive (dead)
               start condition failed at Mon 2014-06-02 20:53:10 UTC; 27s ago
               ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0 was not met
         Docs: man:systemd-vconsole-setup.service(8)
               man:vconsole.conf(5)
```

Somehow it states that

```
    /dev/tty0 was not met
```

but I am unsure what it is trying to tell me. The archlinux linux containers page (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers#Terminal_settings) is not helping me. Can someone please explain the error and how to solve it?

Comment: This has been fixed upstream.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for systemd changing the layout in the first place is probably that you gave read/write access on your consoles to the cgroup.

You can change that with :

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = c 5:0 rw
lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = c 5:1 rw
```